# Get Image from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, code-behind

How can I get an image stored in a application folder from code behind?

I need to convert an image in byte[]. So I do this :

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();            
        System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ResolveUrl("~/Icons/CMJN.png")).Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        var foo = stream.ToArray();
```

But It seems he never find the image with the resolve URL.
I'm in the page load of a page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Server.MapPath to get the physical file path.

```
Server.MapPath("~/Icons/CMJN.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Icons/CMJN.png")).Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```